# C# Interactive - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, c#-interactive

I'm trying to try out some of the mongodb driver using the C# Interactive but as soon as I try to create a `MongoClient` I get the following exception:

```
> var client = new MongoClient();
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  + MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ClientDocumentHelper.CreateOSDocument()
  + Lazy<T>.CreateValue()
  + Lazy<T>.get_Value()
  + MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ClientDocumentHelper.CreateClientDocument(string)
  + MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnectionFactory..ctor(MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ConnectionSettings, MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IStreamFactory, MongoDB.Driver.Core.Events.IEventSubscriber)
  + MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ClusterBuilder.BuildCluster()
  + MongoDB.Driver.ClusterRegistry.CreateCluster(MongoDB.Driver.ClusterKey)
  + MongoDB.Driver.ClusterRegistry.GetOrCreateCluster(MongoDB.Driver.ClusterKey)
  + MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient..ctor(MongoDB.Driver.MongoClientSettings)
  + MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient..ctor()
```

Here is the full details to reproduce:-

Install the latest version of the MongoDB driver via command line.

```
C:\dev>nuget.exe install MongoDB.Driver -OutputDirectory tools -ExcludeVersion

Feeds used:
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\packages\

Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'MongoDB.Driver.2.4.3' with respect to project 'tools', targeting 'Any,Version=v0.0'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'MongoDB.Driver.2.4.3' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'MongoDB.Driver.2.4.3'
Resolved actions to install package 'MongoDB.Driver.2.4.3'
Adding package 'MongoDB.Bson.2.4.3' to folder 'C:\dev\tools'
Added package 'MongoDB.Bson.2.4.3' to folder 'C:\dev\tools'
Successfully installed 'MongoDB.Bson 2.4.3' to tools
Adding package 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.4.0.0' to folder 'C:\dev\tools'
Added package 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.4.0.0' to folder 'C:\dev\tools'
Successfully installed 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation 4.0.0' to tools
Adding package 'MongoDB.Driver.Core.2.4.3' to folder 'C:\dev\tools'
Added package 'MongoDB.Driver.Core.2.4.3' to folder 'C:\dev\tools'
Successfully installed 'MongoDB.Driver.Core 2.4.3' to tools
Adding package 'MongoDB.Driver.2.4.3' to folder 'C:\dev\tools'
Added package 'MongoDB.Driver.2.4.3' to folder 'C:\dev\tools'
Successfully installed 'MongoDB.Driver 2.4.3' to tools
```

Open up the C# Interactive window and import in the dlls

```
Microsoft (R) Roslyn C# Compiler version 2.0.0.61501
Loading context from 'CSharpInteractive.rsp'.
Type "#help" for more information.
> #r "c:\dev\tools\MongoDB.Driver\lib\net45\MongoDB.Driver.dll"
> #r "c:\dev\tools\MongoDB.Bson\lib\net45\MongoDB.Bson.dll"
> #r "c:\dev\tools\MongoDB.Driver.Core\lib\net45\MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll"
> #r "c:\dev\tools\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation\lib\net45\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll"
```

Then try to create `MongoClient`

```
> var client = new MongoClient();
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  + MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ClientDocumentHelper.CreateOSDocument()
  + Lazy<T>.CreateValue()
```

Comment: I don't have your answer but I have done battle with similar daemons. Fusion logging is your friend: 

1) https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

2) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem recently, removing `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation` code from web.config worked: (In case you have windows application, check app.config).

Remove this code and it will work:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.0" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```